# List validation on multiple fields?

Tags: custom-list, list-definition, validation

I would like to validate a list item so that if one field is true, then another must be completed.  If the first one is false, then it can be ignored.

```
=(([Start Deferment]="Specific Date") AND [Start Deferment Date] > TODAY()) OR ([Start Deferment]="Next Payment")
```

This gives an error, so I am guessing my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the validation formulae are similar to Excel:

=OR(AND([Start Deferment]="Specific Date",[Start Deferment Date]>TODAY()),[Start Deferment]="Next Payment")

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Yes it does...i was the OP and this is what solved it?

Comment: My bad, I was trying your solution and getting a syntax error myself due to a typo of mine.

Comment: no worries..had a 'mare getting these right myself :(